# How do I put an ORDER BY in a PRINT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to just return just the last line that the query returns, So I need to put it in DESC order and limit it by 1, but the sql does not like the ORDER BY statement. How would I code this?

````
DECLARE @firstNum INT, @secondNum INT, @thirdNum INT, @evenSum INT
SET @firstNum = 1
SET @secondNum = 2
set @thirdNum = 2
SET @evenSum = 2
WHILE (@thirdNum <= 4000000)
BEGIN
    SET @thirdNum = @firstNum + @secondNum
    SET @firstNum = @secondNum
    SET @secondNum = @thirdNum
    IF (@thirdNum % 2) = 0
    SET @evenSum += @thirdNum
    PRINT 'Answer = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @evenSum)
ORDER BY @evenSum DESC
END```
````

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server

Comment: `PRINT` provides a scalar output message, it doesn't provide a data set. You also have a `WHILE` here; which should really be avodied. This seems like a major [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply print right after the loop:

```
DECLARE @firstNum INT, @secondNum INT, @thirdNum INT, @evenSum INT
SET @firstNum = 1
SET @secondNum = 2
set @thirdNum = 2
SET @evenSum = 2
WHILE (@thirdNum <= 4000000)
BEGIN
    SET @thirdNum = @firstNum + @secondNum
    SET @firstNum = @secondNum
    SET @secondNum = @thirdNum
    IF (@thirdNum % 2) = 0
    SET @evenSum += @thirdNum
END
PRINT 'Answer = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @evenSum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've completely missed the point of what you're trying to achieve don't you just want to do this?

```
DECLARE @firstNum INT, @secondNum INT, @thirdNum INT, @evenSum INT
SET @firstNum = 1
SET @secondNum = 2
set @thirdNum = 2
SET @evenSum = 2
WHILE (@thirdNum <= 4000000)
BEGIN
    SET @thirdNum = @firstNum + @secondNum
    SET @firstNum = @secondNum
    SET @secondNum = @thirdNum
    IF (@thirdNum % 2) = 0
    SET @evenSum += @thirdNum

END
PRINT 'Answer = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @evenSum)
```

What you were trying to do with with the 'ORDER BY'  didn't work because you aren't dealing with a dataset, there's nothing to "order"  - you've got some variables and you're doing some calculations in a loop on them until a certain condition is met - you wanted to know what the value of @evensum was when the loop finished it's last iteration. So all you needed to do was wait for the code to fall out the loop and print the value.